# Writing to a address value from a variable?

Tags: c++, variables, pointers, memory

im trying to write to an address in my own process, so im not trying to write to any other process :P say that i have a variable:

```
unsigned int address = 0xDFCDD8; //just an example, nothing more.
```

how would i go about writing to the address contained inside the variable, since the address is not going to be static :/ i do know that WriteProcessMemory is able to do this, but i feel that this would be kind of an overkill as its mainly used for writing to remote processes :S

so in "pseudocode" kind of it would be like this:

```
int newVal = 10;
0xDFCDD8 = newVal;
```

just that the address would be contained inside a variable :)

any help is greatly appreciated :D

Comment: [Pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)).

Comment: You should read some tutorials about pointers before you ask such a question!

Comment: yea i also thought about pointers :S so i did actually do:
 *(float*) address = newVal;
but it did not seem to work properly so i asked instead. and there is no problem in asking.

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine why you need it, but there's how to do it:

```
uintptr_t address = 0xDFCDD8;
int newValue = 10;
*(reinterpret_cast<int*>(address)) = newValue;
```

Don't do anything like that, please!

Comment: There are valid reasons for using code like this. Self-patching code, especially patching code you don't have source for, detouring function calls, etc, for instance.

Comment: This technique is popular with embedded systems programming to access hardware registers.